# Spring Rest Controller: Correct way to return entities from mapping methods?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have the following Rest `Controller` class that handles `HTTP` requests relating to my `Client` entity?

For context - a `client` (e.g. exercise client) can have one `Trainer`. But a `Trainer` can have many clients.

Am I returning the entities in the correct way from my controller? I am using the Spring `ResponseEntity` class to wrap the Client related responses.Is there any other controller implementations I am missing in order to improve this code? - i.e.

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/clients")
public class ClientController {

    private final ClientService clientService;

    public ClientController(ClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{clientId}")
    ResponseEntity<Client> getClientById(@PathVariable long clientId) {
        Client Client = clientService.getClientById(clientId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Client, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/trainer/{trainerId}")
    ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getClientsByTrainerId(@PathVariable long trainerId) {
        List<Client> clients = clientService.getClientsByTrainerId(trainerId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clients, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Client> createClient(@RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO) {
        Client newClient = clientService.createNewClient(clientDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newClient, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{clientId}")
    ResponseEntity<Client> updateClient(@PathVariable Long clientId, @RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO) {
        Client editedClient = clientService.editClient(clientId, clientDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(editedClient, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Edit: Add Delete method**

```
@DeleteMapping("/{clientId}")
long deleteClient(@PathVariable long clientId) {
    clientService.deleteClient(clientId);
    return clientId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need in the code above for the return types to be `ResponseEntity<>`. You can declare controller methods to return any type of object, and Spring is smart enough to wrap your intended return type in a ResponseEntity as needed.

For example:

```java
    @GetMapping("/{clientId}")
   Client getClientById(@PathVariable long clientId) {
        return clientService.getClientById(clientId);
   }
```

If you want to return a different HTTP status code besides 200 OK, you can use an annotation for that. For example:

```java
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Client createClient(@RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO) {
        return clientService.createNewClient(clientDTO);
    }
```

The only time I ever make controller methods return `ResponseEntitiy<>` is if I have logic in the method that returns different response types (status codes) based on some conditions.

---

As an aside, it's usually not a good idea to return your entities directly in API endpoints. Most of the time you're going to want to transform the entity types into DTO types, to separate the public representation of things from the persistent representations. The DTO can have whatever shape you want to expose to clients, and can vary independently from the domain or persistent form. At first this might seem like unnecessary form of code duplication; sometimes the two never diverge or have differing structure, names, etc. But many times experience has taught us that the domain/persistent entities evolve differenty from the API contract.

Comment: thanks, so return dtos even if the dto I am returning will be the same as the entity, but just without the id? I have added my delete method also - this should just return a long?

Comment: I added some explanation to the "aside" part of the answer. I don't know why a DELETE endpoint would return the ID that it was called with. As a caller of such an API I would not expect that.

Comment: thanks I appreciate it, what should a delete http method return ideally? Just the 200 response code?

Comment: I usually return `void` with a response code of either 200 or 204 (No Content). That's pretty "standard" but keep in mind that REST doesn't really have a standard, only guidelines and conventions.